# Syncronisation tool for dropbox replacement

Tags: sync, cloud-storage

I have several Linux-PCs I want to be synced. I have a server exporting a filesystem via nfs, ftp or sshfs. I mount them to ~/syncenc. With encfs they are mounted to ~/sync. Working directly in this directory is fine as long as the computer is online. But some are Laptops that should keep their home directory local, but sync when online. Both the local as the remote data can change, of course. Also I a file is moved one side it has be move on the other as well, same for dirs. The software should be FOSS.

I'm looking for a software that can do that.
So far i found: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software but the table is rather incomplete.

- **rsync** - does not work bidirectional does it?
- **unisono** - cannot exclude files, there for useless (you cant sync a/b with a recursivly, obviously) also it cannot detect rename/move operations.
- **Dir Sync Pro** - Cannot detect rename/move operations, not suitable.
- **iFolder** - Wikipedia says something about P2P. ?? Also it seems to depend on a special Serversoftware.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be on Linux, you might look at http://www.sparkleshare.org ... seems to be maturing well and has good Linux / Mac / Android support. Windows and iOS are lagging for now, but if you don't need them it might do the trick for you.